# Самый быстрый способ перебора списка

Tags: python, list, список

Мне нужно сделать самый быстрый перебор списка, не просто обычный `for i in spisok`, пожалуйста подскажите разные решения этой задачи.
Мне нужно перебрать данные из БД `sqlite3`, поэтому чтобы он мог так же взаимодействовать с БД, вот пример кода:

```
for row in sql.execute("""SELECT token, user_tg_id FROM users """):
    print(row[1], row[0])
```

Comment: Чем вас обычный `for i in spisok` не устроил?

Comment: Вы полностью задачу сформулируйте. Зачем вы список перебираете, что вы хотите с элементами сделать? От этого зависит.

Comment: Самый быстрый способ перебора - это отказ от полного перебора) Если полностью сформулируете задачу (как вам уже посоветовали, то скорее всего получите адекватные ответы/советы.

Comment: В данном (и похожих) случае затраты времени на любую организацию цикла будут пренебрежимо малы по сравнению со временем работы базы и вывода результата

Comment: `print(*map(' '.join, sql.execute("""SELECT user_tg_id, token FROM users """), sep='\n')`

Comment: Я делаю сейчас телеграмм бота, который будет отправлять уведомления о успешных транзакциях в телеграмм бот. На данный момент я реализовал постоянные ежесекундные request запросы на python к API сайта, который собирает информацию и сравнивает со старой и если полученная информация не соответствует как в БД, то скрипт добавляет эту запись в БД и отправляет в телеграмм бот уведомление пользователю, что совершена новая транзакция.
Перебор бд мне нужен чтобы получить id пользователя в телеграмме и потом при проверке новой информации потом ему ее отправить в телеграмм бот.

Comment: Этот перебор будет совершатся циклично тем самым постоянно проверяя статус пользователе, когда будет много пользователей в бд тогда проверка статуса будет занимать намного больше времени

Comment: Попробуйте познакомится с yield или с асинхронными запросами. можно запариться с тредами. Но помните о том, что большая часть библиотек в питоне для работы с бд, написаны на С-подобных языках . И если Вам уж так нужна очень высокая производительность, посмотрите в строну этих языков.

Comment: Ну асинхронные запросы я сделать, все происходит быстро, но у меня есть другая функция которая отвечает за взаимодействие с пользователем, к примеру добавить кошелек в бд или удалить или же сделать запрос самостоятельно к бд. И когда я использую асинхронные запросы, это функция просто перестает отвечать, хотя для нее я выделил отдельный поток и она запустилась но не реагирует

Comment: @Body, SQLite не позволяет параллельно изменять данные. Читать данные (SELECT) можно многими потоками одновременно, а изменять только одним - он при этом блокирует всю БД (файл с данными). Мне кажется для вашей задачи вам стоит использовать более продвинутые БД - PostgreSQL / MariaDB / MySQL / etc.